# Ocaml error unbound Value

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

When i try to evaluate line 2 or 5 of this program, i get "Unbound value carre" or  "Unbound value bis". 
To evaluate it i use emacs with tuareg, could it be related ?

```
let carre x = x*x;;
carre(9);;

let bis y = y^y;;
bis("ab");;
```

For example, here is what i get for line 2 :

```
# Characters 0-5:
  carre(9);;
  ^^^^^
Error: Unbound value carre
#
```

The code is very simple so i feel like the problem comes from emacs.
I've tried to change function names, variables names, but nothing worked.
Does anybody see what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the first line of your program before the second.

The interpretor doesn't know the definition of `carre` or `bis` until you've evaluated it.